# Django Deployment - scriptProcessor could not be found in fastCGI application configuration

Tags: python, django, iis, web-deployment

I am learning the process to deploy Django Project through IIS and fastCGI. However, I am facing an error `<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration`.

After a little bit of research I've found that this error could be due to rights issue. Hence I've added permission (read, write, execute) for user `DefaultAppPool` in folder Python37 (contains python virtual environment) and similarly I've done this for folder wwwroot which is on `C:\inetpub`.

Python Virtual Environment: `C:\python37`
Web.config file path: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config`

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI" 
      path="*" 
      verb="*" 
      modules="FastCgiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="c:\python37\scripts\python.exe|c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py>" 
      resourceType="Unspecified" 
      requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="c:\python37\scripts\python.exe" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="manhour_site.wsgi.application" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="manhour_site.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

After making changes above I am still facing the similar issue hence I looked at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438459/azure-flask-handler-scriptprocessor-could-not-be-found-in-fastcgi-applicatio).
As per the solution fastCGI settings must be in the `applicationHost.config` file. This file is located on path `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

After following this solution I've made following changes

**applicationHost.config**

Under `<system.webServer>` I've added following

```
       <fastCgi>
            <application fullPath="c:\python37\scripts\python.exe" arguments="c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" maxInstances="4" signalBeforeTerminateSeconds="30">
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="manhour_site.settings" />
                    <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="c:\python37\scripts\python.exe" />
                    <environmentVariable name="WSGI_HANDLER" value="manhour_site.wsgi.application" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </application>
       </fastCgi>
```

I've ran the command as administrator `wfastcgi-enable`.

I need a solution that can point mistake and help in resolving this error.

PS: In my settings.py file I've changed following

```
DEBUG = 'False'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**Edit**
I've added `HttpPlatformHandler` to `web.config`

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="fastCGI" 
      path="*" 
      verb="*" 
      modules="FastCgiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="c:\python37\scripts\python.exe|c:\python37\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
      resourceType="Unspecified" 
      requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>

     <httpPlatform processPath="c:\python37\scripts\python.exe"
                  arguments="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\manhour_site\manage.py --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="c:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="80" />
      </environmentVariables>

  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="c:\python37\scripts\python.exe" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="manhour_site.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The above changes causes error `The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

**Config File**    `\\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config`

Comment: Microsoft recommends HttpPlatformHandler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-httpplatform-handler

Comment: @LexLi I've made changes to `web.config` still getting the error.

Comment: It is **either** HttpPlatformHandler **or** FastCGI, so you **cannot keep both** in the configuration.

Comment: I've kept FastCGI and I am getting an error `python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly` Is it possible due to the fact that I am using python venv.

Comment: For information about "Configure Python web apps for IIS", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019

Comment: Couldn't find the exact solution but after downgrading to Python 3.6 the errors where resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, I encountered, I copied the fullPath and arguments values from the applicationHost.config file, specifically within the fastCgi tag, and then pasted them into the web.config file of my application. Additionally, I made sure to update the

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

line in the applicationHost.config file.